# Add a body class to WooCommerce product category archives that are childless

Tags: woocommerce

Is there a way I can add a custom class to product categories that have no children?

I have category display set to 'Show subcategories', so products are only shown in the final category.

I'd like to add a custom class to this final category so I can do some css shenanigans that will only be applied to category pages that are displaying products... I'm assuming the best way to do this is the add a custom class.

I've found several options for adding classes to parent categories and have tried to adapt them, but can't work out how to get it to work... this one didn't work either:

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'category_has_children' );

function category_has_children($classes){
    
    $children = get_categories(array('child_of' => id,'hide_empty' => 0));
if (count($children) > 1){
    //has childern
    }
    else{
        //no children
        $classes[] = 'childless';
        }
    return $classes;
}
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For WooCommerce product categories use `get_terms()` like:

```
$children = get_terms(array('taxonomy' => 'product_cat', 'child_of' => $term_id,'hide_empty' => 0))
```

Now you need to target product category archives and define the current `$term_id`.

So your code will be:

```php
add_filter( 'body_class', 'product_category_has_children' );
function product_category_has_children( $classes ){
    $taxonomy = 'product_cat';
    $object   = get_queried_object();

    if ( ! is_a($object, 'WP_Term') || $object->taxonomy !== $taxonomy ) {
        return $classes;
    }

    $children = get_terms( array(
        'taxonomy'   => 'product_cat', 
        'child_of'   => $object->term_id,
        'hide_empty' => 0
    ));

    if ( ! is_wp_error($children) && count($children) === 0 ){
        $classes[] = 'childless';
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.